# I found a strange thing in http://projector.tensorflow.org/.I want to make sure it's my problem or the website problem

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, projector

If I downloaded the .tsv sample file it provided.
Then I upload it again and let it calculate the result
Then it stays in the calculation page all the time. Even though I have reduced the amount of data, or imitated its data, and reduced the dimension
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV7tE.jpg)